# Handling error in Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, subscriber

## Problem Description

I have a simple class with simple function `buildUseCaseObservable`. Function should do following

1. Try to get data from Internet first

   - If succeed write data to Database
   - **If failed with exceptions like: `ServerUnavailable`, `SocketException` should read data from database and also should report error.**
   - If receive data, but data was null or empty, should read data from database.

Basically everything works like expected, except bold point. In case something happens while getting data from web, only `onError` is called and `onNext` is not called.

I found out that there is method called `onErrorResumeNext` which is basically doing what I need but in that case I'm loosing error (`onError` is not called, instead `onNext` is called)

## Question

Is the such method like `onCompleteWithError` or if no how to implement such a thing to not lose error?

```
@PerActivity
public class DataInteractor extends Interactor {

    private RestService rest;
    private DataService data;

    @Inject
    AuthorsInteractor(RestService rest, DataService data) {
        this.rest = rest;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    protected Observable buildUseCaseObservable() {
        return Observable.concat(
                rest.getData().doOnNext(data -> data.setAuthors(authors)),
                data.getData())
                .first(data -> data != null && !authors.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in your case it seems like `onError()` and `onNext()` will be mutually exclusive. What I'd go with is a class that will allow you to return both the result and the error:

```
public static class Result<T> {
  T data;
  Throwable error;
}
```

then `onErrorResumeNext()` would look like:

```
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> new Result(data.getData(), throwable))
```

Comment: and is there some more elegant way of doing what I want to do ?

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/) may be useful for you @VictorApoyan. Cheers.

Comment: @YeMinHtut thanks it is useful, but not for my question.